# Sharepoint 2013 and Exchange 2010 : synchronization

Tags: 2013, synchronisation, exchange

I'm starting to use Sharepoint 2013 and trying to synchronize tasks with Exchange (we have an Exchange 2010) by clicking on [the "Sync to Outlook" button in my profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9V2I.png). But I get the followed error:

> We weren't able to sync your tasks. This could be be!cause your mailbox
>   is on an Exchange server that isn't supported for syncing tasks.
>   Please contact your administrator for more help.

I read about Exchange 2013 synchronization, but nothing about 2010. Someone [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bd7446be-cd01-4098-9ebd-6b67fc2cc1e2/error-when-trying-to-sync-tasks-to-outlook-from-sharepoint-2013) had the same error than mine. A possible answer is the version of Exchange: a 2013 version seems to be required.
But they talk about Office version, than O365... So the answer is not satisfying enough.

Is that the source of my problem? Compatibility?

In this tutorial from [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554516.aspx), they only mention Exchange 2013, but I can't find anything about 2010.

So, I'm asking you. Thanks in advance for the help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is by design. When you get to Exchange 2013, you will have the ultimate experience of aggregration of all tasks across SharePoint and Exchange. With the creation of the cross farm aggregatinon of tasks to the newsfeed, the connecting to outlook feature was taken away. Once you are on Exchange 2013 that aggregration feature will work in Exchange and SharePoint which will of course rock.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the ultimate answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not have Exchange 2013, the solution is to deactivate the Farm Feature "Farm Level Exchange Task Sync".

Steps:

- Open Central Administration
- Go to System Settings -> Manage Farm Features
- Deactivate the Feature Farm Level Exchange Task Sync

You find a more detailed description in [this post](http://gokanx.wordpress.com/tag/we-werent-able-to-start-syncing-your-tasks-because-one-or-more-prerequisites-for-connection-to-exchange-server-could-not-be-found-please-contact-your-administrator-to-resolve-the-issue/)!

Comment: The referenced blog post is down :(