# Sync with Outlook option disabled

Tags: 2013, calendar, outlook

I have enabled "Team Site" feature in my publishing site. After that I was able to add "Calendar" web part.

Then I tried to sync it with Outlook but the option to sync with Outlook is disabled in ribbon. I am logged in as Farm Administrator.

How to sync calendar with Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the feature before it becomes available.

Go to Settings -> Site Settings -> Manage site features and look for **Offline Synchronization for External Lists** and click activate.

Now go to the list/webpart again and you should see the button enabled.

**EDIT**

as noted by oc3lot you need exchange, no need for outlook or any other office installed on the server!

> 1.Go to the SharePoint site and browse to the page where you will integrate the calendar.
>
> 2.Click Page and Edit Page.
>
> 3.Click Add a Web Part. Click the Outlook Web App category.
>
> 4.Click the My Calendar Web Part, and click Add.
>
> 5.Click "Open the tool pane" on the My Calendar Web Part.
>
> 6.Enter https://mysite.outlook.com in the Mail server address field.
>
> 7.Enter the email address for the account's Exchange calendar. Click OK.

to know what your mail server is:

[image]

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/662/1819.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecc5a39e-22f2-48ce-abfb-b34ef7c22e09/outlook-web-access-web-part-sharepoint-server-2013-was-deprecated

Comment: Ok I will try this solution tomorrow when I go to work.

Comment: I enabled this feature but the button is still disabled. I am logged in as Site Collection Administrator.

Comment: By the way on the machine where I am testing, Outlook or any other MS Office component is not installed. May be this is an issue?

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: There is no "Outlook web app" category when I went to add web part. I can see "Calendar" web part but it is under category "Apps" and it called "Calendar" and not "My Calendar". May be this is the reason that I am not using the correct calendar web part? Or do I need local admin permissions on this machine? Just to note Outlook or any other MS Office component is not installed on this machine.

Comment: Ok I managed to add "OWA" web part. I went to web part gallery and added it. Now I have added OWA calendar in my page and now I can see it. So this is it? I mean it's the same like synching with Outlook? Secondly does it mean every user will need to "Edit" page and then add web part from there? Which means each user need edit permission on this page!?

Comment: ok, first to understand what webpart you need and what to have, we need to know what version of sharepoint 2013 are you using?

Comment: yes its it, its the same as sync-ing with outlook! i presume you have sharepoint online? please follow this! this will sync with your account that you logged in with exchange ;) so one webpart for all! http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2012/05/29/outlook-web-app-in-sharepoint-online.aspx

Comment: No I am not using SharePoint online. The OWA web part is working fine but just one small problem. Every time I close browser and go to that page where this web part is added, it asks for Outlook user/password. Shouldn't it automatically pick up since I am logged in to Windows?

Comment: look at permissions part http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199.aspx you need to make some ammendments: configuring the Outlook Web App virtual directory to use Integrated Windows authentication. Integrated Windows authentication lets users who've already logged on by using their Active Directory account use Outlook Web App without having to enter their credentials again.

Comment: the ammendment needs to be done in exchange which you can follow here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998638(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: I think it is more complicated than that. Because when I open OWA directly in browser then it doesn't ask for user/password. But when I add it as a web part then it asks for it. I read another thread here that kerberos authentication needs to be implemented to make it work.

Comment: what version of exchange server you running? 2010? your hitting a double sign in, one for your current login and another for the webpart! if your on 2010 than you need to give the directory specific security type e.g. intergrated win authentication

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Exchange Server running in your environment? This is a requirement to having Outlook Sync to SharePoint. If you're running a 2013 environment, you should be running Exchange Server 2013 as well.

If you do have an Exchange Server, is there any additional server software running with it, such as Enterprise Vault? If so, it may affect the connectivity to SharePoint, which is the situation in our current environment.

Comment: Yes Exchange is running but I think it is not 2013 (will confirm tomorrow). Can it SP 2013 only sync with Exchange 2013?

Comment: You can run Exchange 2010 with SharePoint 2013, but lose some functionality. There's a related thread here:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74880/sharepoint-2013-and-exchange-2010-synchronization

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Site Settings -> Manage site features and look for Offline Synchronization for External Lists and click activate.

Now go to the list/web part again and you should see the button enabled.