# SharePoint 2013 Integration with Exchange 2010

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-integration, exchange-server

Is there any documentation with a list of features and capabilities by which SharePoint 2013 can be integrated with Exchange 2010.

Any help would be greatly accepted. I work as an SharePoint Admin in an organization and have been assigned to start researching a way to integrate Exchange 2010, Outlook 2007, 2010 together with SharePoint 2013 Standard edition. Any input would help my research efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no such document avaiable for this intergration, You have to test all the possible scenrio to check if they are work with exchange 2010 or not. Couple of these feature are not working with exchange 2010.

- eDiscovery in Exchange
- Automatic Task Synchronization with Outlook
- Site Mailbox feature

There is a Legacy Task Synchronization mode available that will work with Exchange 2010 if you turn off the Farm level feature controlling Exchange 2013 task synchronization.  It lets users manually sync specific task lists with Outlook.  But there is no task aggregation.

There is one white paper which talk about new features and how to turn them off when using Exchange 2010.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38799

Couple of helpful resources:
[Sharepoint 2013 and Exchange 2010 : synchronization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74880/sharepoint-2013-and-exchange-2010-synchronization)