# SharePoint 2013 sync with Outlook + Exchange 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, exchange-server

I would like to know the procedures or any good web URL to sync SharePoint 2013 with Exchange 2010 ( sync with outlook).

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of data you want to sync with exchange?

Comment: What exactly do you want to sync, and in what directions?

Comment: I would like to sync all the task that I create in outlook to be synced to SharePoint. The version of SharePoint that I am using in 2013 and my mailbox Exchange Server is 2010. Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1):

If you want built in syncronysation feature - it does not exist

[Sharepoint 2013 and Exchange 2010 : synchronization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74880/sharepoint-2013-and-exchange-2010-synchronization)

You can create custom solution (TimerJob) for sync with exchage using [EWS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx).